# Compiling Android Framework (AOSP)

Tags: android, linux, compilation, frameworks, android-source

I'm trying to compiling the Android framework on Ubuntu 16.10 (64 bit).
During the compiling process, with this command "**make -j1**" I obtain this problem:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=ITL41D
============================================
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp
<command-line>:0:0: warning: "_FORTIFY_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from frameworks/base/include/utils/Vector.h:20:0,
                 from frameworks/base/include/utils/AssetDir.h:24,
                 from frameworks/base/include/utils/AssetManager.h:24,
                 from frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.h:10,
                 from frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/new:41:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: File o directory non esistente
compilation terminated.
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/AaptAssets.o] Errore 1
```

Have anyone any idea of how resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed this [pre-build step](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-required-packages-ubuntu-1404) :

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 \
  lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache \
  libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip
```

For your particular case it seems that `multilib` is missing

Comment: But this are pre-build step for Ubuntu 14.04 while I'm using Ubuntu 16.10.
Anyway I try this command but this returned me this error:
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/lib32z1-dev_1%3a1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu5_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).
Any other ideas?

Comment: maybe [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zlib/+bug/1512992) and [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zlib/+question/290379)

Comment: For your precise problem does just `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib` fix the issue ?

Comment: No it' doesn't works, because when I install multilib as you say to me the O.S. say me that i just have it:
g++-multilib is already the newest version (4:6.1.1-1ubuntu2).
gcc-multilib is already the newest version (4:6.1.1-1ubuntu2).
So it doesn't works :(